# Am I managing asyncio tasks (python 3.9) in a proper way?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.8, python-3.9

I'm developing a scraper (python 3.9), I need to launch make_attempt() and, depending on the results of its execution, to launch additional tasks that should work concurrently.

First I create initial task and add it to a list where I store all asyncio tasks:
`self.data["worker"]["tasks"]`
Then I launch:
`await asyncio.gather(*self.data["worker"]["tasks"])`

In make_attempt() I wait for results of POST-request to a server (I use aiohttp client), and, based on the result, I either add new tasks, or repeat make_attempt() after a small delay.

I stop the current task and remove it from the list with asyncio tasks, and then I add new tasks.

```
async def make_attempt(self):
    attempt: int = self.data["res"]["attempt"]

    await self.do_something()
    await sleep(1)

    for task in self.data["worker"]["tasks"]:
        print("Task name: %s" % task.get_name())
        if task.get_name() == str(attempt):
            task.cancel()
    self.data["worker"]["tasks"] = [task for task in self.data["worker"]["tasks"] if task.get_name() != str(attempt)]

    if 1 > 0:  # a condition to start make_attempt() again
        self.data["worker"]["tasks"].append(asyncio.create_task(self.make_attempt(), name=attempt))
        await asyncio.gather(*self.data["worker"]["tasks"])

async def run(self):
    self.data["worker"]["tasks"].append(asyncio.create_task(self.make_attempt(), name=self.data["res"]["attempt"]))
    await asyncio.gather(*self.data["worker"]["tasks"])
```

I'm new to asyncio so maybe you could point me to mistakes or could suggest a better implementation.

Upd. Here is a schema of what I want to achieve:

[image: tasks_schema]

main_task should be run and if the result is ok, it should launch a couple of instances of another tasks (see loop2). When a result of a task in loop2 is obtained, a new subtask should be run.
main_task should wait either for all tasks in loop2 to be finished or a Timeout to be fired.
All tasks in loop2 should work concurrently.

UPD 2. This code produces `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` after about 1000 cycles of execution of the check_base_url() method.

```
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    async def get_response(self, session, url, method="get", *args, **kwargs) -> Union[
        ClientResponse, None]:
        for _ in range(0, 20):
            if method == "get":
                try:
                    response = await session.get(url, headers={}, proxy="_proxy", *args, **kwargs)
                    if response.status > 399:
                        raise ScraperError(response.status)
                    await sleep(0.1)
                    return response
                except (ClientError, ScraperError) as err:
                    await sleep(0.25)
                    continue
            else:
                try:
                    response = await session.post(url, headers={}, proxy="_proxy", *args, **kwargs)
                    if response.status > 399:
                        raise ScraperError(response.status)
                    await sleep(0.1)
                    return response
                except (ClientError, ScraperError) as err:
                    await sleep(0.25)
                    continue
        return None

    async def get_captcha(self) -> SolvedCaptcha:
        for _ in range(0, 20):
            captcha = await self.task_1()
            if captcha:
                continue

    async def final_task(self, url) -> bool:
        async with ClientSession(cookies={}) as sess:
            resp_step1: Union[ClientResponse, None] = await self.get_response(sess, "url", "post",
                                                                              data={})
            if resp_step1:
                resp_step2: Union[ClientResponse, None] = await self.get_response(sess, "url", "get")
                if resp_step2:
                    captcha: SolvedCaptcha = await self.get_captcha()
                    if captcha:
                        resp_captcha: Union[ClientResponse, None] = await self.get_response(sess, "url",
                                                                                            "post",
                                                                                            data={})
                        if resp_captcha:
                            if 2 > 1:
                                print("FINISHED")
                                return True
                        else:
                            return False
                    else:
                        return False
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False

    async def add_task_3(self) -> None:
        if 2 > 1:
            subtasks = [asyncio.create_task(self.final_task(self.data["res"]["slots_urls"][0]))]
            await asyncio.gather(*subtasks)
        else:
            await self.add_task_3()

    def parse(self, html: str, url: str) -> None:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        # do parsing

    async def task_2(self, url) -> bool:
        async with ClientSession() as sess:
            resp: Union[ClientResponse, None] = await self.get_response(sess, url)
            if not resp:
                return False
            html = await resp.text()
            self.parse(html, url)

    async def add_task_2(self) -> None:
        if 2 > 1:
            subtasks = [asyncio.create_task(self.task_2(url)) for url in ["url1", "url2"]]
            await asyncio.gather(*subtasks)

    async def task_1(self) -> bool:
        self.data["res"]["captcha_requested"] += 1
        res = await self.captcha.task_1()
        if not res:
            return False
        return True

    async def add_task_1(self) -> None:
        if 2 > 1:
            subtasks = [asyncio.create_task(self.task_1()) for _ in range(0, 5)]
            await asyncio.gather(*subtasks)

    async def get_calendar_url(self, sess) -> bool:
        resp: Union[ClientResponse, None] = await self.get_response(sess, "url", method="post",
                                                                    data={})
        if not resp:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    async def check_base_url(self) -> bool:
        async with ClientSession() as session_0:
            return await self.get_calendar_url(session_0)

    async def schedule_tasks(self):
        def start_again() -> bool:
            if 2 > 1:
                return True
            return False

        res_base_url: bool = await self.check_base_url()
        if res_base_url:
            tasks = [asyncio.create_task(self.add_task_1()),
                     asyncio.create_task(self.add_task_2()),
                     asyncio.create_task(self.add_task_3())]
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            if start_again():
                await sleep(0.1)
                await self.schedule_tasks()
        else:
            await self.schedule_tasks()

    async def run(self):
        await self.schedule_tasks()
```

Comment: Does it work? Or what is the problem?

Comment: Rather than iterating over your list of tasks multiple times, you could use a dictionary keyed by `attempt`.

Answer (score 1):

`asyncio.gather` won't update when you add new tasks.
You should just create new tasks wherever you need them. Quick rule of thumb everything you `aio.gather()` no matter wherever you do that will execute in parallel. As an example there will be total of 9 `some_async_task` running in parallel

```py
async def nested():
    tasks = [some_async_task(), some_async_task(), some_async_task()]
    await aio.gather(tasks)

async def main():
    tasks = [nested(), nested(), nested()]
    await aio.gather(tasks)
```

This is what you can do:

```py
import asyncio as aio

async def task():
    ...
    await subtask()

async def subtask():
    # anything here
    pass



async def main():
   r = await aio_http_request()
   if should_create_tasks(r):
       tasks = [task(), task(), task()]
       await aio.gather(tasks)
   else:
       await aio.sleep(5)
       await make_attempt()

 
async def run():
   await make_attempt()
```

Here A, B, C execute concurrently. While Main Task -> Task -> Subtask are sequential.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
|                                                                        |  
|                +-----------------+                                     |  
|                |                 |                                     |  
|                |    Main Task    |                                     |  
|                +-------+---------+                                     |  
|                        |                                               |  
|                        |                                               |  
|                        v                                               |  
|    +-+-------------+---+-------------++------+-------------+--------+  |  
|    | |      A      |   |      B      |       |      C      |        |  |  
|    | |  +-------+  |   |  +-------+  |       |  +-------+  |        |  |  
|    | |  |TASK   |  |   |  |TASK   |  |       |  |TASK   |  |        |  |  
|    | |  +---+---+  |   |  +---+---+  |       |  +---+---+  |        |  |  
|    | |      |      |   |      |      |       |      |      |        |  |  
|    | |      |      |   |      |      |       |      |      |        |  |  
|    | |      |      |   |      |      |       |      |      |        |  |  
|    | |      |      |   |      |      |       |      |      |        |  |  
|    | |  +---+---+  |   |  +---+---+  |       |  +---+---+  |        |  |  
|    | |  |subtask|  |   |  |subtask|  |       |  |subtask|  |        |  |  
|    | |  +-------+  |   |  +-------+  |       |  +-------+  |        |  |  
|    | |             |   |             |       |             |        |  |  
|    | +-------------+   +-------------+       +-------------+        |  |  
|    |                                                                |  |  
|    +----------------------------------------------------------------+  |  
|                                                                        |  
|                                                                        |  
|                                                                        |  
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Remember here SUBTASK of A can happen before TASK of B completes because they are not bound (they are concurrent).

Comment: I added a schema to my question to make it more clear. Won't the queue block execution of tasks concurrently?

Comment: queue won't block the execution but I had misunderstood the question, so thanks for great work on question diagram.

Comment: Just as a reference you might find this helpful [What the heck is event loop - youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: It's weird, when I pass the list of the tasks `tasks = [task(), task(), task()]` to `asyncio.gather()`, I'm getting a warning `RuntimeWarning: coroutine  was never awaited` . So I replaced it with `tasks = [await task(), await task()]`, but I'm getting this error:  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 821, in gather
    if arg not in arg_to_fut:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: To eliminate the warnings and errors I did like this:
```tasks = [(asyncio.create_task(self.task(), name="task1")), ...]
            
await asyncio.gather(*tasks)```

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I've updated it. That is an actual error because if we don't await then we're not really executing the function.

Comment: After about 1000 cycles of execution I have got this: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. Does it happen because I have to manually remove all tasks except on the main_task every time the cycle finishes, or does this error occur because of a mistake in my code?

Comment: This error is not related to async/await itself. But wherever you're calling same function inside itself, try to convert it to a loop instead. I will have more context if you share the code.

Comment: I added the code to the question description, it's too long to post it here. I decided to keep the structure of my class in order not to remove something important for diagnosing )

Comment: https://bpa.st/EPJY2 can you try something like this, I guess the error is there because we're calling schedule_task as recursion.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to to use [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#queue) to manage the pending jobs in your application. You can then create a number of worker tasks that receive jobs from that queue and can also add new jobs.

In the example the actual work (POST request and process some data) is simulated by using [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping). Some jobs will produce new jobs while others will not.

Workers will pick up and work on jobs concurrently this way.

The `Manager` is in charge of creating the job queue and waiting for all items to be processed. After that it will cancel all workers and the program terminates.

### Code

```
import asyncio
import random


class Worker:
    def __init__(self, num, target_q):
        # Worker number
        self.num = num
        # The job queue
        self.target_q = target_q
        # Create asyncio task
        self.task = asyncio.create_task(self.run())

    async def run(self):
        # Work on jobs until task is cancelled
        while True:
            print(f"Worker {self.num}: Waiting for new target")

            # Receive a new job from the queue
            target = await self.target_q.get()
            print(f"Worker {self.num}: Processing target {target}")

            try:
                # Simulating some work (e.g. a POST request)
                await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

                # Depending on the outcome, some new work results
                # 0-2 new targets are generated
                new_target_count = random.randint(0, 2)

                if new_target_count > 0:
                    print(
                        f"Worker {self.num}: Target {target} generating {new_target_count} more targets"
                    )
                    for _ in range(new_target_count):
                        # Create a new random target
                        new_target = random.randint(1, 10000)

                        # Put new targets into queue. This will wait if queue is
                        # currently full.
                        await self.target_q.put(new_target)

            finally:
                print(f"Worker {self.num}: Target {target} done")

                # Decrease queue count by one
                self.target_q.task_done()


class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        # A common queue holding the jobs for the workers. It just stores
        # integers here but could hold any data.
        self.target_q = asyncio.Queue(10)
        # The list of workers
        self.workers = None

    async def run(self):
        # Create some initial work
        await self.target_q.put(1)

        # Create 3 workers
        self.workers = [Worker(num, self.target_q) for num in range(3)]

        # Wait until queue of unfinished tasks is empty
        await self.target_q.join()

        # Cancel other workers
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.task.cancel()


def main():
    manager = Manager()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(manager.run())
    loop.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Sample outcome

```
$ python workers_test.py
Worker 0: Waiting for new target
Worker 0: Processing target 1
Worker 1: Waiting for new target
Worker 2: Waiting for new target
Worker 0: Target 1 generating 2 more targets
Worker 0: Target 1 done
Worker 0: Waiting for new target
Worker 0: Processing target 320
Worker 1: Processing target 5807
Worker 0: Target 320 done
Worker 0: Waiting for new target
Worker 1: Target 5807 done
Worker 1: Waiting for new target
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this example, I'll definitely try this approach. If I understood correctly, I'll need to implement all logic concerning tasks execution order inside the method run() in class Worker, right?
So what am I afraid of is that I'll have a if-else hell. Initially I wanted to find a way to add tasks inside methods in my class, but as I still don't know how to implement it correctly, I'd rather try your approach

Comment: `run()` is the entry point for the worker task. So, it will define what the worker is going to do. Why are you afraid of an "if-else hell"? You can always create more methods on the `Worker` class if the `run()` method becomes messy. You can also create other types of workers and more queues to reflect a more complicated workflow.

Comment: Concerning the new diagram: What do you mean with `loop1` and `loop2`? Are you referring to the asyncio event loop? There is always only one event loop in asyncio.

Comment: Anyways, from looking at the diagram I assume you would have 3 different types of workers: `task`, `another task` and `subtask`. `main_task` is the manager. All tasks interact with other tasks using queues, either taking something from or putting something in a queue (or both). In the diagram you would need 3 queues. One input queue for every worker type. `main_task` would put items into the `task` and `another task` queues. They put their results into the `subtask` queue.

Comment: The `main_task` would wait until either all queues are done, meaning no more available jobs OR a timeout task is done (which is just an `asyncio.sleep` call), whatever finishes first. In the end it would cancel all tasks as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what are you looking for .
1st. You don't have to store the `coro`.
2nd. Your code on step `create_task` throws the `coro` to the `async loop` without waiting but you call `await asyncio.gather` again.

if you just want make it run forever or quit on `if condition` please check out the code below.

```py
async def make_attempt(self):
    await self.do_something()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if 1 > 0:  # a condition to start make_attempt() again
        return await self.make_attempt()

async def run(self):
    await self.make_attempt()
```